# Drop down menu clips/shrinks items Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am creating a dropdown menu where the items contain a text element and an icon (a spacer in between); but only the first text is shown completely. The icon is only visible when there is another item taking more space.

[image]

```kotlin
@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), Alignment.Center) {

        Box() {
            var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

            IconButton(onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.MoreVert, contentDescription = null)
            }

            DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
                MyMenuItem("item 1")           // Icon visible
                MyMenuItem("item 2")           // Icon visible
                MyMenuItem("item 3 long text") // Icon width shrunk to 0
                MyMenuItem("item 4 long te")   // Icon visible but shrunk
            }

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyMenuItem(text: String) {
    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { }) {
        Text(text)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = null) // <-- Icon
    }
}
```

### Note :

1. I have also tried using `Row()` and `Surface()` in place of `DropdownMenuItem()` but the result is similar.
2. Giving width to the `MyMenuItem()` works; but I want it to size itself automatically based on content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, to create such a layout you just need to apply `Modifier.weight(1f)` to your `Text`.

You also need `Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)` for your `Column` to make the width equal to the widest item, but in your case it's already built into `DropdownMenu`.

But then [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198206454) pops up, which doesn't allow you to properly size your `MyMenuItem` with `Icon` inside. Please put a star to draw more attention to it.

As a temporary solution until this bug is fixed, you can specify the size of the icon manually, like this:

```
// copied from the source code as it's internal
const val MaterialIconDimension = 24f

@Composable
fun MyMenuItem(text: String) {
    DropdownMenuItem(
        onClick = { }
    ) {
        Text(text, Modifier.weight(1f))
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, 
            contentDescription = null, 
            modifier = Modifier.size(MaterialIconDimension.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yesterday I solved this issue by doing exactly what you said. But I wasn't aware of the `IntrinsicSize` bug. Thanks for letting me know! Might be useful for others until the bug is fixed.

Comment: `Modifier.weight(1f)` is the only thing that worked for me. I spent hours looking for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try with a leading/trailing Icon like this:

```
DropdownMenuItem(
            text = { Text("New") },
            onClick = { onNewClicked() },
            trailingIcon = {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.TwoTone.RestartAlt, contentDescription = "New Item")
            }
        )
```